# getting name value from a string using TSQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**I just edited the question to make it more clear.. please help**

I am using SQL server 2008.

I have a column containing the following strings..

```
http://www.microsoft.com?abc=1234&def=567&ghi=891
http://www.microsoft.com?abc=4587&def=567&ghi=891
http://www.microsoft.com?abc=2478&def=567&ghi=891
http://www.microsoft.com?abc=9874&def=567&ghi=891
http://www.microsoft.com?abc=5412&def=567&ghi=891
```

In the following string, how can I get values of "abc" using TSQL?

the result should be ...

```
abc

1234
4587
2478
9874
5412
```

Please let me know.

thanks

Comment: Are you reading this from a table or trying to parse some input? Also do you expect the position of abc to change or is it expected to be a static bit of data?

Comment: Are you only looking for the first parameter, or all parameters in the URL string?

Comment: I do no expect position of abc to change.

Comment: I am only looking for first parameter 'abc'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @x varchar(100)
set @x = 'http://www.microsoft.com?abc=1234&def=567&ghi=891'

declare @param varchar(100)

set @param = 'abc='
select SUBSTRING(@x, charindex(@param, @x)+LEN(@param), CHARINDEX('&', @x+'&', charindex(@param, @x)) - CHARINDEX(@param, @x)-LEN(@param)) as abc

set @param = 'def='
select SUBSTRING(@x, charindex(@param, @x)+LEN(@param), CHARINDEX('&', @x+'&', charindex(@param, @x)) - CHARINDEX(@param, @x)-LEN(@param)) as def

set @param = 'ghi='
select SUBSTRING(@x, charindex(@param, @x)+LEN(@param), CHARINDEX('&', @x+'&', charindex(@param, @x)) - CHARINDEX(@param, @x)-LEN(@param)) as ghi
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the substring method on t-sql, but you would have to know the start and length parameters. i mean if the string value changes, it won't work.